Mobilenetv2 transfer learning
Goal:
Transfer learning Mobilenetv2 (input size 224x224 and it's own preprocessing (resize + central_crop + normalization)) as encoder for Unet with input size 512x512 using pytorch.
What I've done:

Created architecture of such an Unet
Loaded MobileNet_V2_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2
Started learning and saw that loss is high and stays the same
Loaded MobileNet_V2_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1
Started learning and saw that everything is fine and model converges

All trainings were done without preprocessing because it operates with 224x224 images. The only thing I did is normalizing to [0;1].
Questions:

Why V2 weights haven't managed to start converging?
Do I loose accuracy throwing away imagenet normalization from preprocessing step?
Should I add one extra conv+pooling layer to increase receptive field twice because input size was doubled?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
